# Select rows around a specified row, combined with WHERE and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, row

I have a table with 3 fields: `id`, `public`, `date`.

How can I make a MySQL query so that the rows are ordered by `date`, rows having `public = false` are omitted, and only the 5 rows before and the 5 rows after the row with `id = x` are fetched? (The row with `id = x` can of course also be fetched.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "before" and "after" refer to the date, then you can use `union all`:

```
(select t.*
 from table t
 where t.public = false and
       t.date <= (select t2.date from table t2 where t2.id = x)
 order by date desc
 limit 6
)
union all
(select t.*
 from table t
 where t.public = false and
       t.date > (select t2.date from table t2 where t2.id = x)
 order by date asc
 limit 5
)
```

The first subquery gets 6 rows whose date is one or before the "x" date.  The second gets 5 rows strictly afterwards.